# Matlab function uint8 in R

Tags: r, matlab, binary, uint8array

How I could generate a `uint8` object in `R` with similar characterization that I could get from `uint8` function in `Matlab` ? I have tried [this](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2018/04/29/uint8-package-for-an-unsigned-8bit-integer-type-in-r/) github link, but the result is different. For example :

```
R :
b02 <- as.uint8(  2)
b0a <- as.uint8( 10)
bff <- as.uint8(255)

bff + b0a
[1] 9
bff/b0a
[1] 25
b02 ^ b0a
[1] 0

is.numeric(bff)
[1] FALSE
> class(bff)
[1] "uint8"

str(b02)
 'uint8' raw 02
str(b02)
 'uint8' raw 02
str(bff)
 'uint8' raw ff

Matlab :

b02=uint8(  2)
b02 =
  uint8
   2
>> b0a =uint8( 10)
b0a =
  uint8
   10
>> bff =uint8(255)
bff =
  uint8
   255

bff + b0a
ans =
  uint8
   255
bff/b0a
ans =
  uint8
   26
b02 ^ b0a 
ans =
  uint8
   255
isnumeric(bff)
ans =
  logical
   1
>> strcmp(class(bff),'uint8')
ans =
  logical
   1

class(b02)
ans =
    'uint8'
>> class(b0a)
ans =
    'uint8'
>> class(bff)
ans =
    'uint8'
```

Comment: Did you tried `mmap` package ?

Comment: @AliHadjihoseini yes, did not work !

Comment: What specifically is the behavior you need. Is it just that you need these numbers not to overflow when adding?

Comment: @MrFlick I want something exactly similar to Matlab Function, since I'm trying to read a serialized data from a database which I have a Matlab script for desalinize the data and I want to be able to do it in R.

Comment: @MrFlick Adding is not the only difference also when dividing, Matlab and R behavior is different !

Comment: Well, you need to describe inside the question exactly what you need to happen. Otherwise this assumes that we have access to the source code for the Matlap `unit8` object or somehow we've memorized all the behaviors of the object. Your example only seem to show addition so it's not clear what you need. And if you're trying to read serialized data you'll probably be using functions more like `readBin`. It's better if you show the problem you are really trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

It seems unlikely that solving the problem as stated is going to help you towards your ultimate goal. In R the closest thing to a uint8 is `raw` format. This can be converted to any other data type you choose, so it is best to learn to work with it.

For completeness, it is worth pointing out that with R's S3 object-oriented system it is very easy to define your own uint8 class. Here's an extremely simplified example, which can take numeric or raw data and performs simple arithmetic as expected.

```r
uint8 <- function(x)
{
  if(class(x) == "uint8") x <- unclass(x)
  if(is.raw(x)) x <- as.integer(x)
  if(is.numeric(x)) x <- as.integer(x)
  if(!is.integer(x)) stop("uint8 only takes numeric or raw types")

  if(any(x >= 256 | x < 0)) stop("uint8 numbers must be between 0 and 255")
  x <- floor(x)
  class(x) <- "uint8"
  return(x)
}

print.uint8 <- function(x) print(as.raw(x))

b02 <- uint8(  2)
b0a <- uint8( 10)
bff <- uint8(255)

b02
#> [1] 02

b0a
#> [1] 0a

b02 + b0a
#> [1] 0c

bff / b02
#> [1] 7f
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `0` is a valid value for a `uint8`, shouldn't your line 8 be: `if(any(x >= 256 | x < 0)) stop("uint8 numbers must be comprised between 0 and 255")` ?

Comment: Yes @Hoki. I'll change that. To be honest, this isn't an implementation anyone would actually use anyway (I hope), more of an exercise to show that creating a uint8 is possible but completely superfluous in R